# Downgrade SSIS 2012 packages to SSIS 2008? Or modify in VS2013?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, ssis

We currently have a server with `Windows Server 2008`, `SQL Server 2008 R2`, and `VS 2008`. To work in any `SSIS dtsx`, I have to connect directly to the server and work from there. It's an inconvenience.

I recently installed VS 2013 locally, so now I can modify any `SSRS` reports in VS 2013 and publish them to our server, even though it has `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

I tried doing the same thing with the SSIS projects: modify them locally in VS2013 and copy them in the server for `SQL Server Agent` to execute. Unfortunately, it will not execute.

So my question is: can I downgrade a VS2013 DTSX file so that it can be run in SQL Server 2008? [This link](http://vaniecastro.com/2015/02/26/how-to-downgrade-sql-server-integration-services-2014-packages-to-2012/) shows how to downgrade from SSIS 2014 to SSIS 2012 by altering the XML file, so maybe I'm thinking that it *could* be done.

If not, would it be possible to modify, in VS2013, a DTSX file created in VS2008?

If not possible either, would upgrading our server to `SQL Server 2012` help this particular situation?

Essentially, I want to work to work with the `DTSX` packages locally and publish, deploy, or copy them to the server. All the DTSX packages were initially done in VS2008, but I can recreate them as long as I can do that locally in my PC.

Thanks.

Comment: It cannot be done. Prior to VS 2015/SQL Server 2016, you had no option. Now, you have the ability to target SQL Server 2012/2014/2016 but 2005/2008 did not make the cut. An alternative approach is to describe your packages as Biml and then when you emit as SSIS, it will work with whichever version of Visual Studio you're using

Comment: You need a tool called Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) to edit 2008 R2 packages.  According to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi) there is no web download for this.  If you still have the SQL Server 2008 installer you can use that to install BIDS on your machine.